# Angular 2 Material

Tags: angular, material-design

After update angular 2 to rc5 and material to alpha.7-4 I have a trouble with building on webpack.

For example if I am adding MdInput in directives of some Component I have an error:

```
node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:151
                                throw e;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
```

In example of official repository they have strange import

```
import {MaterialModule} from '@angular2-material/all/all';
```

I don't have this module and couldn't find this path in my node-modules. But if copy this file into directory there is no effect.

Answer (score 0):

All you need should be this in your app.module.ts

```
import {MdInputModule} from '@angular2-material/input';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MdInputModule],
  ...
})
```

Also `@angular2-material/core` has to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 Materal 'all' Module appears to have been removed. I came into Angular 2 just recently with RC5 and found creating a Layout module to be sufficient to an 'all':

layout.module.ts:

```
 import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { MdCoreModule } from '@angular2-material/core';
 import { MdSidenavModule } from '@angular2-material/sidenav';
 import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';
 import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
 import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     CommonModule, MdCoreModule, MdSidenavModule, MdToolbarModule, MdCardModule, MdButtonModule],
   exports: [MdCoreModule, MdSidenavModule, MdToolbarModule, MdCardModule, MdButtonModule]
 })
 export class LayoutModule { }
```

Then I import this into my app module into the 'imports' array. That's all I've needed so far and every other module/component I include in app with Material elements inherits the md directives.

Comment: When I try add some MdModule in my Module I have a webpack error from my question. It's not Angular it' webpack